# Preemtion of Linux kernel threads with disabled interrupts

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, gpio

I am trying to create a stable 1Mhz clock using a Linux kernel driver and GPIO on a Raspberry Pi 4. Unfortunately when I connect my logic analyzer to the GPIO Header (pin 39/40 which is GPIO21 and GND), the resulting clock source sometimes stumbles, as if the kernel thread was preempted. Otherwise on the other parts it looks fine. Why does it happen? Is it possible to fix it somehow by disabling something more?

The code is below, I have modified a kernel module sample. (`cntfrq_el0` is equal to 54M no matter the CPU power settings, which was set to 'performance' during the run BTW)

```c
#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>         /* Needed for the macros */
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>

#define GPIO_26 21

static int __init hello_start(void)
{
    unsigned i;
    u64 freq, base_clock, current_clock, target_elapsed;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading hello module...\n");
    if (!gpio_is_valid(GPIO_26)) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_26 is not valid\n");
        return -1;         
    }
    if (!gpio_request(GPIO_26,"GPIO_26")) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_26 cannot be requested\n");
        return -1;         
    }
    gpio_direction_output(GPIO_26, 0);

    asm volatile ("isb; mrs %0, cntfrq_el0" : "=r" (freq));
    printk(KERN_INFO "freq = %llu\n", freq);
    freq *= 1;
    freq /= 1000000;
    
    local_bh_disable();
    local_irq_disable();
    target_elapsed = 0;
    asm volatile ("isb; mrs %0, cntvct_el0" : "=r" (base_clock));
    for(i = 0; i < 500000; ++i) {
        target_elapsed += freq;
        // udelay(20);
        while(true) {
            asm volatile ("isb; mrs %0, cntvct_el0" : "=r" (current_clock));
            if (current_clock-base_clock >= target_elapsed)
                break;
        }
        gpio_set_value(GPIO_26, i & 1);
    }
    local_irq_enable();
    local_bh_enable();

    // printk(KERN_INFO "elapsed = %llu\n", current_clock-base_clock);

    gpio_free(GPIO_26);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_end(void)
{
    // printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye Mr.\n");
}

module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

This code has another problem, which makes no sense to me. When I first start, then `gpio_request()` is unsuccessful, and the module is unloaded, but then the next `insmod` succeeds. Then after `rmmod`, the first `insmod` fails again and so on. Why?

**Additions on 2023-06-01:**

1.
As it turned out the insmod/rmmod success/failure happened because gpio_request() returns <0 on error, and the code above tests for == 0, so that was a false alarm.

2.
Using the gpiod_*() non-legacy functions instead of the gpio_*() functions changes nothing.

3.
I have managed to ioremap() the memory at 0xfe200000 (and not 0x7e200000 as the pdf says - the right value can be found by "sudo cat /proc/iomem"), and set/clear the output pin manually. It did not change anything. Using ioremap_np(), or writing by "=", or "iowrite32()" or "writel()" changes nothing.

4.
Measuring CNTPCT_EL0 vs CNTVCT_EL0 changes nothing. It would be good to find some documentation about the difference between the physical and virtual count registers, but then there is no measurable difference anyways. CNTVCTSS_EL0 (Counter-timer Self-Synchronized Virtual Count register) does not exists. There is no counter offsets either.

5.
CNTFRQ_EL0 (Counter-timer Frequency register) does not change during the runtime, remains 54 million.

6.
My last code checks that over 25000 clock ticks (50000 changes) after the GPIO write call, the current clock value differs from the last one by 540 (49999 times), or by 541 (only once). So the timing looks completely stable measured by the counters, while from the logic analyzer it stumbles.

7.
The reason I would spend so much CPU on the clock signal because this is not the end goal, obviously. The end goal is to connect a Commodore 64 SID and VIC chip to the Rapsberry PI, and run the CPU/CIA/drive emulation code on the PI's CPU. Unfortunately with these timings it seems kinda impossible.

**Additions on 2023-06-03:**

8.
Thanks for the information about the "sloppy GPIO logic analyzer" project. I have checked their code, and the only difference is that they use the preempt_disable_notrace() call as well. Unfortunately it is disabled when defined(MODULE), but I copied the code to my source file and tested it. No difference.

9.
I have also tested that my logic analyzer is not broken, and a clock signal generated from a microcontroller board is perfectly fine. Also tested that the same stable clock from the microcontroller captured by the driver in the PI4 results in unstable timestamps, so there is definitely something wrong on the  PI4 side. As if it would be running on a hypervisor. Or as if preemption still happens for some reason.

10.
Tested to run the code inside a locked spinlock to test if local_irq_disable() is disabled when defined(MODULE), but no difference.

Comment: With disabled interrupts a thread cannot be interrupted and thus cannot be be preempted. "When I first start, then gpio_request() is unsuccessful, and the module is unloaded. But then the next INSMOD succeeds. Then after RMMOD, the first INSMOD fails again and so on. Why?" - You could start to debug that problem by printing **error code** of `gpio_request` call. The actual value of that error code could give you some hints.

Comment: You must not use `gpio_*()` APIs, they are deprecated and already half-removed from the kernel. That's the main cause of your issue, besides the other code issues.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to generate the clock signal in software? Seems like a waste of CPU cycles.

Comment: You may read this to understand how to achieve something similar: https://lore.kernel.org/r/20220329091126.4730-1-wsa+renesas@sang-engineering.com.